# Evolution Calendar doesn't show CalDAV events

Tags: release-hera, calendar, evolution

I've added a new collection account on Evolution to display all my calendars like I do on KOrganizer but on Evolution, even though they show up on the list on the left as enabled, there is no events in the main schedule.

So far I've tried adding the calendars individually and adding them by selecting "on the Web" in the setup wizard, but none of them showed the events in the end. Only adding them as .ics files by downloading them from Nextcloud and adding them by import worked, though I don't know how I would then sync them back to the cloud if I used that option.

I'm on elementary OS 5.1 and using Evolution 3.34.3 from Flatpak/Flathub.

Did anyone encountered a problem like this, and if so is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I share your experience with CalDAV on Elementary, because even Elementary calendar does only show some of my CalDAV entries and not others.

I will file a bug report in the coming days and I would encourage you to do the same. You can do it [here](https://github.com/elementary/os/issues)

Answer (score 0):

I use GNOME Online Accounts to provide applications access to my Nextcloud instance.
I tested this with the Evolution Flatpak and it works great for automatically connecting to my Nextcloud calendars and shows events like it should.
If you want to set this up, just follow these steps.

1. Install GNOME Online Accounts.

```
sudo apt -y install gnome-online-accounts
```

2. Open the Online Accounts settings in GNOME Control Center using the following command.

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center online-accounts &>/dev/null &
```

3. Now just add your Nextcloud account using the panel that appears.
   This should make your Nextcloud calendars available in Evolution.

I should note that it is likely that in elementary OS 6 this workaround won't be necessary due to better integration with the Evolution Data Server and support for Nextcloud accounts directly in elementary's Online Accounts settings.